# Dump ruby DateTime to YAML timestamp reliabely with ruby 1.8 and 1.9

Tags: ruby, datetime, yaml

I have a problem, YAML doesn't work quite the same in ruby 1.8 and 1.9. Especially when dumping a DateTime object.

Ruby 1.8:

```
require 'yaml'
YAML.dump(DateTime.now)
=> "--- 2012-06-21T14:29:02+02:00\n"
```

Ruby 1.9:

```
require 'yaml'
YAML.dump(DateTime.now)
=> "--- !ruby/object:DateTime 2012-06-21 14:29:41.874102975 +02:00\n...\n"
```

What bothers me is the **!ruby/object:DateTime** tag which is quite annoying. using a Time object in 1.9 solves the problem:

```
YAML.dump(DateTime.now.to_time)
=> "--- 2012-06-21 14:31:37.904841646 +02:00\n...\n"
```

The problem is that to_times doesn't exist in ruby 1.8. Moreover ruby 1.8 Time class doesn't handle timezones (impossible to create a Time object with an arbitrary timezone).

If possible, I'd like the time format to be the same.

How could I dump a DateTime object in YAML then?

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.9.3 the default YAML engine changed from Syck to Psyck, but both are available.

Ruby 1.9

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
YAML.dump(DateTime.now)
 => "--- 2016-10-19T13:12:22+02:00\n"
```

And if you want use the old YAML engine in Ruby 2.0 or later (where Syck was definitely removed), you can use the gem [syck](https://rubygems.org/gems/syck/versions/1.1.0).

Ruby 2.0:

```
require 'syck'
YAML.dump(DateTime.now)
 => "--- 2016-10-19T13:14:37+02:00\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution which is far from being perfect would be:

```
class DateTime
  def to_yaml_time
    if DateTime.method_defined? :to_time
      # to_time is defined, and Time can be converted with timezones, perfect
      to_time
    else
      # We're a bit less lucky, but hopefully in this version of Ruby, DateTime
      # can be exported without garbage in the timestamp
      # ("!ruby/object:DateTime")
      self
    end
  end
end
```